# Virtual Clicking

Tags: vb.net

How do I make so that the program clicks on certain location based off of x and y coordinates that I tell it to click on? Right now I have: `mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, x, y, 0, 1)`

But when it executes it clicks wherever my mouse is, regardless of what x and y coordinates I pass into it.

Here's the exact code:

```
For n = 0 To dt2.Rows.Count - 1

        command = dt2.Rows(n)("Command")
        pos = dt2.Rows(n)("Position")
        x = Mid(pos, 21, 4)
        y = Mid(pos, 28, 3)

        Try

            If command = "" Then

            End If

            If command = "Double Click" Then
                mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, x, y, 0, 1)
                mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP, x, y, 0, 1)

            End If

            If command = "Left Click" Then
                mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, x, y, 0, 1)

            End If

            If command = "Right Click" Then
                mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN, x, y, 0, 1)

            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try

    Next
```

`dt2` is a datatable

Comment: You need to call `mouse_event` first to move to (x,y) and then call again to click. Or set the `MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE` flag as well as the mouse up/down flag.

Comment: Is that just `mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE)`... maybe? lol

Comment: [See here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646260(v=vs.85).aspx) - you can combine several flags in one call or make several calls.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `mouse_event` first to move to (x,y) and then call again to click. Or set the `MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE` flag as well as the mouse up/down flag.

[See here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646260%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - you can combine several flags in one call or make several calls.

Comment: You could also set the mouse position like so: `Cursor.Position = New Point(X, Y)`.